# How do I change the z-index of the datepicker calendar popup?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I'm trying to modify the z-index of the Kendo UI DatePicker Control so that the calendar that pops up shows up behind some tooltips on my component's view. How can I change this index value?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCwpz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This(JavaScript) should work:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(modifyZIndex); 

function modifyZIndex() 
{ 
    window.Telerik.Web.UI.Calendar.Popup.zIndex = 14000; 
}
```

14000 is just a big number , you can put any large number there.